# Where to find the Snowpipe errror log

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowpipe

I have created the below snow pipe. when I check the status of the pipe it says running.
For some reason it is not copying the data, could someone please let me know how to check the error logs of Snowpipe?

The copy into `"INGESTION_TEST"."TEST"."CAR_BASELINE_V2"` works fine when executed independently and is able to insert the data successfully.

Only when I run from snow pipe is it not copying data and not able to find the errors related to snow pipe.

```
create or replace pipe INGESTION_TEST.TEST.CAR_BASELINE_V2_PIPE auto_ingest=true as COPY INTO "INGESTION_TEST"."TEST"."CAR_BASELINE_V2"
                    FROM (
                    SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(METADATA$START_SCAN_TIME)::STRING AS SNOWPIPE_INSERTION_TIME,$1:ID::STRING, $1:UUID::STRING, $1:CAR_NAME::STRING, $1:CAR_CATEGORY::STRING, $1:CAR_PRICE::STRING, $1:COLOR::STRING, $1:CREATED::STRING, $1:UPDATED::STRING
                    FROM @INGESTION_TEST.TEST.nexgen_stage/CAR_BASELINE_V2/ 
                    ) 
                    FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = PARQUET);
```

Answer (score 1):

[COPY_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/copy_history)

> **This table function can be used to query Snowflake data loading history along various dimensions within the last 14 days.** The function returns load activity for both COPY INTO  statements and **continuous data loading using Snowpipe.** The table function avoids the 10,000 row limitation of the LOAD_HISTORY View. The results can be filtered using SQL predicates.

```
select *
from table(information_schema.copy_history(TABLE_NAME=>'"TEST"."CAR_BASELINE_V2"'
                         ,START_TIME=> DATEADD(hours, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())));
```

Comment: I tried this and Query produced no results

Comment: when I check the status of snow pipe , it is running , but not copying the data.